# GA4 BigQuery daily Export 'device.operating_system' field reporting values as 'WEB'

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

[image]

I am very confused that in my GA4 bigquery export events table, for dates before 07/01/2021,  this field (device.operating_system) seem to be only reporting value 'WEB'.

In the GA4 WEB UI the OS seems to be reported correctly.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this from Google. Wondering if it's a bug?